# getting sevletconfig object in zk

Tags: java, servlets, zk

How can I get the servletconfig object in zk framework?

As we can get httpservletRequest and httpservletresponse using nativerequest and response but what about servletconfig?

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted. Seems a legit question in ZK's context.

Comment: I agree with kachhalimbu so question score is 0 again :)

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for [WebApp](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/6.0.0/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/WebApp.html) instance and you can get it by calling [Desktop.getWebApp()](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/6.0.0/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/Desktop.html#getWebApp%28%29). WebApp is a wrapper that wraps both ServletContext & ServletConfig and has similar API as both.